# Get CSS ::after with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I was wondering how would you get data that is inserted to the page with css ::after. Obviously with a simple getPage() I won't be able to get the information. It prevents users from selecting the text, but it also prevents getting the data. Is there any solution to this?

Thank you